# Using terpri to insert newlines in buffer

Tags: newlines

I am using `(insert "\n")` to insert a newline in a specified buffer.  Is this the recommended way to do it?  I have seen `(terpri)` but cannot get it to make a newline.

```
(defun fire-clock (bufrn)
  "TODO."
  (interactive)

  (let ( (ss (nth 0 (decode-time)))    ; seconds
         (mm (nth 1 (decode-time)))    ; minutes
         (hh (nth 2 (decode-time))) )  ; hours

    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create bufrn)

      (text-mode)  
      (goto-char (point-min))

      (dotimes (i (/ ss 5))
        (firefly-ticker-second 'green))
      (insert "\n")
      (dotimes (i (% ss 5))
        (firefly-ticker-second 'blue)) )))
```

Comment: Show what you tried wrt using `insert` vs `terpri` -they don't do the same thing. Ask a *specific* question about something you tried that you think doesn't work as you expected. Start your recipe from `emacs -Q`. And of course, start by reading the doc for `insert` and `terpri`.

Comment: As shown in the example I am using `(insert "\n")`.  I do not understand `terpri` very well and how to use it after reading the doc.

Comment: What is `PRINTCHARFUN`?  The doc seems to assume that all users know what things like `PRINTCHARFUN` mean.

Comment: No: the doc tells you that the argument `PRINTCHARFN` is a stream and also tells you what happens if that argument is not provided.  In general, doc-strings name arguments in upper case so they can be easily referred to in the succeeding description.

Comment: So I need a buffer (which excludes a buffer name).  For this situation, `insert` seems to be the appropriate thing to call.  If a buffer name is passed, how can I get that buffer to `terpri`.  What do you think about the use of `terpri` in this instance?